# Is there a sorted atomicAdd or equivalent

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I have a working detection and tracking process (pixel image in rows and columns) which does not give perfectly repeatable results because its use of atomicAdd means that data points can be accumulated in different orders leading to round off errors in the calculation of centroids and other track statistics.

In the main there are few clashes for the atomicAdd, so most results are identical. However for verification and validation I need to be able to make the atomicAdd add these clashing data points in a consistent order, such that say thread 3 will beat thread 10 when both want to use the atomicAdd to add a pixel on the row N that they are processing.

Is there a mechanism that allows the atomicAdd to be deterministic in its thread order, or have I missed something?

Comment: No, there is no way to achieve this. The underlying reason is that the execution order in CUDA is undefined. You can't know in what order threads will be executed and you can't impose any order on operations threads will perform in parallel.

Comment: @talonmies, it was more about what alternatives there are that would achive the desired order, whether it is some hidden p-code, or extra instructions, etc, so that, for test purposes, we can validate other parts of the code run identically (and find which areas are most susceptible to round off and order errors etc)

Comment: I understand your question, but the answer is that there is not. Floating point (I presume this is floating point arithmetic we are talking about here) isn't associative, and throw in non deterministic execution order and you have a degree of unpredictability in the results.

Comment: just seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/11226746/717355 which suggest I could do an extra sort step if the count>1 which would then make the down stream code become [more] deterministic. At the moment I have a data dumper (CPU side) that pre-sorts the data  before sending to a log for comparison between runs (all input data read from file), so moving the 'sort' to the atomicAdd (Ugh) may need to be the approach, but it isn't my first choice..

Comment: For verification and validation you should just work with margins of error instead of exact comparisons.

Comment: @RogerDahl, The issue is that the margins of error grow exponentially when looking at validation of cascaded feedbacks. While the 'tracker' looks good, sometimes it declares 4 tracks and sometimes 5 tracks (out of thousands of potential tracks), probably because of error growth. Which isn't good for checking & verification, hence the desire to 'force' repeatability to help confirm the subtle causes of the variation.

Answer (score 2):

Check out "Fast Reproducible Atomic Summations" paper from Berkeley.

http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hdnguyen/public/papers/ARITH21_Fast_Sum.pdf

But basically you could try something like finding a sum of abs values along with your original sum, multiply it by O(N^2) and then subtract and add it to/from your original sum (sum = (sum - sumAbs * N^2) + sumAbs * N^2) to cancel out the lowest bits (that are indeterministic). As you can see the upper bound grows proportional to N^2... so the lower the N (number of elements in the sum) the better is your error bound.

You could also try Kahan summation to reduce the error bound in conjunction with the above.

Comment: Many thanks for the link. I will have a read of it, even though my project has moved on, so I'm not working directly on GPU coding at the moment. but hopefully soon...

Comment: Actually now that i think of it, the sum of abs values itself will be indeterministic so the subtraction can be slightly off. So you might have to use n*atomicMax(x[i]) instead of sum(abs(x[i]))