# Write data only from selected lanes in a Warp using Shuffle + ballot + popc

Tags: cuda

I'm having some issues while trying to save some shared memory to improve the processing. In this code every thread pick a template index (t_initdwl) from host and expand it until the upper limit before the next kernel process it.

The idea is to use shuffle + ballot to "reserve" the right amount of space to write only indexes from threads that did not exceeded the upper limit. Since it is an array of limits, first every col limit is tested then it is written. The number of "expanded entries" varies according to the values in the initial index but, but once the thread surpass the limit, any further increment are not valid, so it sets play=false (just to be safe) and returns.

The issue is the bCol value that is always trasnp_line + 1, giving the idea that popc is not working correctly in this line only, since 1 is the correct value for the lineID 0 only. I'm not getting any error,

The expected results is the correct position to the line to write, taking in account the number of lines that still "playing" (have not returned yet).

```
__global__ void dwLgen(const int maxthreads, short* __restrict__ kpL, int* nkpl, 
        const short* __restrict__ init_dwL, const short rloops){
    __shared__ short t_initdwl[1024][24];

    const int warpID(threadIdx.x / warpSize);
    const int laneID(threadIdx.x % warpSize);
    const int st(rloops + 2);
    const int stb((p - kpMax + 1 + 1) * BUFFERSIZE_MAX); 
    const int idx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int cAlive, tAlive, bCol, bline, transp_line;  
    int i, j; 
    bool volatile play(true);

    if (idx < maxthreads) {
        for (j = 0; j < st; j++){
            t_initdwl[threadIdx.x][j] = init_dwL[idx + j * BUFFERSIZE_MAX];
        }
        __syncthreads();
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < st; j++)
                if ((t_initdwl[threadIdx.x][j] + i) > dwLt[j]) {
                    play = false;
                    return;
                }

            cAlive = __ballot((play == true));
            tAlive = __popc(cAlive);
            bline = __ffs(cAlive) - 1;
            if (laneID == bline)
                transp_line = atomicAdd(nkpl, tAlive);
            transp_line = __shfl(transp_line, bline);

            tAlive = exp2f(laneID + 1); 
            bline = tAlive & cAlive; // the bline value is ok
            bCol = transp_line + __popc(bline); // but __popc(bline) become always 1


            for (j = 0; j < st; j++)
                kpL[bCol + j * stb] = t_initdwl[threadIdx.x][j] + i;
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I have read the question twice now and honestly do not know what it is you are asking. It seems you are looking for help with debugging. If so, please post self-contained buildable and runable code together with sample input plus expected and actual output: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well, you are kind right. When I do check step by step, I see the expected value at `bline = tAlive & cAlive` but, `kpL[bCol + j * stb]` always evaluate to **transp_line + 1**...

I'm guessing that I should mask or recast or something else the **bline** at `__popc(bline);`

It's possible to notice the wrong result in the data (in the next kernel that uses it) and in the current kernel at the last line.

Comment: It appears that you are allowing some threads to become inactive (e.g. via your `return` statement).  Have you considered carefully the behavior of the various instrinsics when there are inactive threads?  For example, the behavior of warp shuffle is undefined when the target warp lane is inactive.   Without a [mcve] I can only make guesses.

Comment: @njuffa, while producing the MCVE, I notice a possible variation that work as planned, thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the support!

After reading the @njuffa and test a code variation it work.

The previous approach to bitmask the laneID was incorrect.
Using exp2f only produced the expected result for the 1st and last lane.

**`tAlive = exp2f(laneID + 1)`**

was replaced by:

**`tAlive = 0xffffffff >> (warpSize - laneID);`**

So, now it works, just fine.

**Edit**: 
Today I found by a chance a [post in Parallel for ForALL](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/voting-and-shuffling-optimize-atomic-operations/), **that explain very well how to use shuffle, ballot and popc in order to filter threads that contribute to the main result.**

I hope that this edit help someone to find it, since I did not in the past.

Regards,